# What happens between the transition of yugas?

Tags: history, yuga

According to the scriptures, there are yugas in these worlds. After completion of one yuga, the world collapses even an ant cannot escape from death but according to the history we find so many temples today in India which are built in dwapara yuga and also in thretha yuga.

As an example 'Kedharnath temple' was built by Pandavas i.e in the Dwapara yuga. Then how come these temples exist even till today? Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do Vedas say about transition to Kali yuga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16426/do-vedas-say-about-transition-to-kali-yuga)

Comment: World doesn't end after every yuga. It ends after a kalpa and a minor pralaya is created after a manvantara. Yuganta doesn't occur. Kalpanta is the word.

Answer (score 3):

World does not collapse after every Yuga.

The collapse of earth & solar system only occurs at end of 1000 Chatur-Yugas (1 chatur yuga = krita    + treta + dwapara + kali yuga = 4.32 million years)

And that too is only partial because higher worlds like Satya loka will still exist as long as Brahma lives, whose life-span is 100 years, where each year has 360 days, and each day = 2000 Chatur-Yugas (1000 daytime, 1000 nighttime)

After Kali Yuga ends (4 lakh+ years from now), there will be a period of prolonged rains, and then Krita Yuga will start all over again.

The age of earth can be easily calculated as one-daytime of Brahma = 1000 * 4.32 million, or 4.32 billion years.
Scientific analysis of carbon dating rocks comes pretty close to this value (4.54 ± 0.05 billion years). Over time science might get more refined and arrive at same answer as given in our ancient scriptures.

http://veda.wikidot.com/vedic-time-system

Comment: Scientific Analysis claims that earth is ALREADY 4.32 ±0.05 billion years old. But according to Hinduism the present creation is only 1.97 billion years old. We are in the 28th chaturyuga of the 7th manvantara where each manvantara has 71 3/7 chaturyuga in it. And age of each chaturyuga is 4,320,000 human years. Do your calculation.

Comment: @NipunJoshi - there are different 'creations'. one where entire earth is created from scratch, and one where it is just submerged in water, and then water dries off and lives start over. we are in 28th chaturyuga of THIS svetavaraha kalpa. During brahma's nighttime, only 3 worlds are destroyed (or submerged, depends). Do your scriptural study. 2

Answer (score 0):

According to the scripture, at the transition of every Yuga-s, the **world doesn't collapse** always. Mainly "Morality" or *Dharma* in general, would become weaker. As discussed in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19601/1049), Morality looses its 1-1 leg with every Yuga change from:

```
Krita --> Treta --> DwApara --> Kali ...  <morality restored>
```

Now, according to a source in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19603/1049), at the end of a Kaliyuga, all creation will happen afresh. Hence, the possibility of big annihilation (*MahA-pralaya*) is during one particular Kaliyuga.

---

In general, it's better to avoid Yuga theory, because there are too many theories around it. The world is so big and diverse that we can't say for sure that which country is living in which Yuga, as per *Dharma*. Some countries practice higher morality and some lower.

Answer (score 0):

It's would be very easy to say but very difficult to understand that in each transition our Earth remained same but only existance of humans changed the only reason is our Earth passed through a very fine black hole because of which everything went into a new level of energy and started with a different world. Even now you can notice speed to time has increased, if you observe it will be noticeable but not visible. This is not the end of Kaliyug, our consciousness in going to a different level each and every second. There will be a huge shift in consciousness.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).